# programming with business intelligence studio

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids

does BI studio come bundled with another software? i am trying to create a report server for SSRS but am not able to find BI on my computer and cannot find a place where to download.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install it when you install SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a plug in for Visual Studio.

And an option in the "normal" SQL Server install which should install a VS express version.
But [SQL express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/default.aspx#Installation_Options) can include both BI and VS too.

Edit: BI studio can be seen when you start a new VS project.

If it's not there, your installation is wrong somewhere. What do you have installed now please?

Comment: im sorry so can u tell me how do i get his plug in?